# Turn off single process swap and overcommit

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

Two questions:

1. Is there some way to turn off swapping for a given process, i.e., is it possible to kill a certain process if it uses all the system's primary memory available?
2. How do I deactivate memory overcommit in a Linux system?

**Context**:

I'm running a distributed application, and I'd like to have a process killed once the system ran out of primary memory. The process is quite heavy on hard disk communication, for what I find reasonable to check the memory usage *programatically*, like:

```
std::ifstream statm("/proc/self/statm");
size_t mem_virt, mem_rss, mem_shared;
statm >> mem_virt >> mem_rss >> mem_shared;
if (mem_virt == MAX_SYSTEM_PRIMARY_MEMORY) {
    // kills current process
}
```

But if there was some set of command lines capable of turning off the swap for a given process, that would be definitely better.

Yet, I still don't know how to turn off the overcommit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disallow swapping in your application by calling `mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE)`, see the man page.

You can disable overcommit:

```
$ sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2    # policy number 2
$ sysctl vm.overcommit_ratio=0     # ratio = 0%
```

Running without swap is generally a terrible idea. Now all anonymous mmaps will be be forced to be backed by RAM, even if they are not used. Unix needs swap, even if nothing is actually swapped.

Comment: This sounds to me like the best solution. Thanks very much! (:

Comment: If I read correctly (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) by setting `vm.overcommit_ratio=0` like above, you limit total memory allocations to the size of only the swap. I tried the above, and got into a state where nothing can run as all allocations fail. I guess the system has already used more memory than the size of the swap. Even `ls` gives `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory`. I think you meant to set the percentage to 100, no?